# Insertion in a model where a relationship is one to many by only one model

Tags: php, laravel

I want to insert in a relation where relation from inspection to inspection_details is one to many. Where one inspection may have multiple details. Problem is i have one model "Inspection". How do i insert or retrieve data from inspection_details table.

[image: Table structure is this]

Code of Inspection model have used

```
 class Inspection extends Model
 {
    protected $fillable =[
       'schedule_id', 'inspector', 'comments', 'signature'
    ];


    public function details()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Inspection', 'inspection_details');
    }
 }
```

But i am not able to insert or retrieve record of details table.

Code i have used with tinker:

```
 $ins = App\Inspection::find(1)
 $ins->details
```

I am getting instances of details, but i don't know how to insert data in inspection_details table.

Comment: You say "one inspection may have multiple details", but then in the model class you write `public function details()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\Inspection', 'inspection_details');
    }`. Why so? Shouldn't it be `$this->hasMany('App\InspectionDetail', ...`?

Comment: That's my problem. Why do i need to create an another model 'App\InspectionDetail'. is it necessary? it is not possible to work just with one model?

Comment: No it is not possible without creating a second model.

Comment: If you don't want to create another model, then you may have to handle the insertion of records in "inspection_details" by raw sql queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the relation between `inspection` and `inspection_details` is wrong, an `inspection` has many `inspection_details` so you would reference that like this:

**Inspection Modal**

```
public function details()
{
   return $this->hasMany('App\InspectionDetail');
}
```

And it's inverse relation from the `inspection_detail` to the `inspection` like this:

**InspectionDetail Modal**

```
public function inspection()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('App\Inspection');
}
```

In terms of saving a new detail that is linked to an inspection you first fetch the inspection to which the detail should be linked:

```
$ins = App\Inspection::find(1)
```

After that define your new `inspection_detail`:

```
$insDetail = App\InspectionDetail::Create(array(
    // your parameters that need to be set
));
```

Then bind it to the `inspection`:

```
$ins->detail = $insDetail;
```

And at last save it to the database:

```
$ins->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you should change.

Currently you are using `belongsToMany`. This is used when you have a [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relation.

Also you are relating your model to itself. `belongsToMany('App\Inspection', ...)`.

This is an example how to solve your problem:

```
class Inspection extends Model
{

    protected $fillable =[
       'schedule_id', 'inspector', 'comments', 'signature'
    ];


    public function details()
    {

        // I assume you also created a model InspectionDetail for you details table
        // 
        return $this->hasMany('App\InspectionDetail');

    }

}
```